# Responsive Form Vertical Alignment

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a form layout like that on the image you can see below. That seems as I wish when page is full size (on computer). Here there's something I want that distance between inputs to be less.

[image]

I also want these inputs all to be vertical. In the picture also it is, but I want it to be vertically aligned when it's 425px (which is mobile). Here it's 1148 width but not like in the first picture. Also input width is too large. It should be smaller because I'll expect only number as input from user

[image]

This project was made using Angular. Below is my css and html. I took this form on the internet which is very close to my approach so CSS came from there. Don't mind id of inputs etc.

```css
        * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    form {
      padding: 1em;
      background: #f9f9f9;
      border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
      margin-top: 2rem;
      max-width: 600px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      padding: 1em;
    }
    form input {
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
      background: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
    }
    form button {
      background: lightgrey;
      padding: 0.7em;
      border: 0;
    }
    form button:hover {
      background: gold;
    }
    
    label {
      text-align: right;
      display: block;
      padding: 0.5em 1.5em 0.5em 0;
    }
    
    input {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0.7em;
      margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    }
    input:focus {
      outline: 3px solid gold;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 200px) {
      form {
        overflow: hidden;
      }
    
      label {
        float: left;
        width: 110px;
      }
    
      input {
        float: left;
        width: calc(100% - 200px);
      }
    
      button {
        float: right;
        width: calc(100% - 200px);
      }
    }
```

```html
    <form class="form1" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" style="padding:30px;  ">
                  
           <div class="row" fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-md="row" fxLayoutGap="5px" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                   
           <div class="col">
            <label for="firstName" class="first-name">Number</label>
            <input id="firstName" type="text">
      
            <label for="lastName" class="last-name">Number</label>
            <input id="lastName" type="text">
      
            <label for="job">Number</label>
            <input id="job" type="text">
      
            <label for="age">Number</label>
            <input id="age" type="text">
      
            <label for="email">Number</label>
            <input id="email" type="email">
            <label for="firstName" class="first-name">Number</label>
            <input id="firstName" type="text">
      
            <label for="lastName" class="last-name">Number</label>
            <input id="lastName" type="text">
      
            <label for="job">Number</label>
            <input id="job" type="text">
      
            <label for="age">Number</label>
            <input id="age" type="text">
      
            <label for="email">Number</label>
            <input id="email" type="email">
           </div>
           <div class="col">
            <label for="firstName" class="first-name">Number</label>
            <input id="firstName" type="text">
      
            <label for="lastName" class="last-name">Number</label>
            <input id="lastName" type="text">
      
            <label for="job">Number</label>
            <input id="job" type="text">
      
            <label for="age">Number</label>
            <input id="age" type="text">
      
            <label for="email">Number</label>
            <input id="email" type="email">
    
            <label for="firstName" class="first-name">Number</label>
            <input id="firstName" type="text">
      
            <label for="lastName" class="last-name">Number</label>
            <input id="lastName" type="text">
      
            <label for="job">Number</label>
            <input id="job" type="text">
      
            <label for="age">Number</label>
            <input id="age" type="text">
      
            <label for="email">Number</label>
            <input id="email" type="email">
           </div>
         </div>             
    </form>
```

Comment: Are you going to use any of UI-framework? Even Bootstrap probably?

Comment: I decided to use bootstrap but couldn't be satisfied

Comment: How so?
It would be pretty straightforward with bootstrap. You can always do:
```
<div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="firstName" class="first-name">Number</label>
        <input id="firstName" type="text">
</div>
```
pretty much for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is happening because you are using width in percentage so it calculates according to the screen resolution.

Change the width of the input from percentage to fixed width and you will get your desired output.

```css
@media (min-width: 200px) {
  form {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  label {
    float: left;
    width: 110px;
  }

  input {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
  }

  button {
    float: right;
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
  }
}
```

Try replacing the width of input from `calc(100% - 200px) to 40px` in the above mentioned media query.

Comment: Thanks that works to make it more similiar as I wished,I'll work on it

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Bootstrap:

```
<form class="form1" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" style="padding:30px;">                  
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">Number</label>
        <input id="firstName" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName">Number</label>
        <input id="lastName" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <!-- and so on -->
</form>
```